# Java Desktop Client with Java EE Server?

Tags: jakarta-ee, java

I've been coding in J2SE and now I'm currently working on a project that requires me to have a Java Desktop app to interact with a Java EE server for several activities such as database connections. I'm still new to Java EE. May someone guide me on where to start? What particular resource/ebook should I take a look on to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with this:

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/

You don't say which Java EE app server you intend to use (Glassfish, JBOSS, WebLogic, etc.)  I'd also recommend looking at the tutorials for your particular vendor.

As far as your client/server interaction goes, the moment you say "desktop" I think "Swing".  If that's the case, you can easily have it use back end services using either EJBs or web services.  The latter will be more reusable, because they use HTTP as their wire protocol; EJBs use RMI, so they're usually called by Java clients.

Answer (score 0):

If the only aim of your application is to have a Desktop app with database connectivity, then you do not need Java EE server at all. Since JDBC code can be written in normal java files (which will have your app code i.e the swing code).

Comment: already had this in mind but the  requirements are that I use a server app.